# Google Checkout Merchant account in In_App billing?

Tags: android

What is the importance or usage of 'Google Checkout Merchant account' in android in-App purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Checkout Merchant account is basically used to set up an account to maintain your paid app's purchase details. Without this account, you cannot have paid apps on android market.There are only limited countries that support having google merchant account. If your country falls under that list, then you can have paid apps have maintain billing for your apps through this account. Hope it helps :)